# How come "screw over" means "to cheat"?

Tags: etymology, phrasal-verbs, phrase-origin

I looked it up [in Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/screw_over), and I've found out that the term "screw over" means "to cheat someone, or ruin their chances in a game or other situation."

I want to know how that term came about? What is its origin? And what does "over" mean here?

Comment: @LatiffaLe It looks like you can log in using a new identity. If you now have two accounts, you can ask the Stack Exchange staff for them to be [merged](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Comments here have been deleted because **answers go in the answer box.**

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure anyone has researched this, but it is presumably related to the phrasal verb "fuck over." [Green's dictionary of slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/xd7dvoq) dates "fuck over" back to at least 1965. John Strachey's *The End of Empire* [used it in 1960](https://books.google.com/books?id=5DMuKOVPnjsC&pg=PT230&dq=fuck+over&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiwkY2_mJb9AhWdGlkFHf46Aow4ChDoAXoECAUQAw#v=onepage&q=fuck%20over&f=false), though, so it appears to be older.

Answer (score 0):

*screw* as such is of a somewhat uncertain origin. The mechanical sense could be an allusion to pig-tails, inasmuch as screws have windings. In this sense, to screw *over* can be torturing a piece of gear, destroying the nut. As a metaphor, this could easily mean *to overstay one's welcome*. That would be a plausible null hypothesis.

However, there is a range of German idioms with one refering to *scheren* "to shear, shave" collocated with *über* "over", though that's more often *barbieren*: *jemanden über den Löffel barbieren* "to screw somebody over".

Röhrich (Redewendungen) explains this, that barbers were generally not deemed trustworthy, and refers to a practice of shoving a spoon under the cheek of the person to be shaved so as to create a smooth surface in the case when there are no teeth to do the job. This doesn't impress me as very believable. Anyway, it means the idiom has a history because Röhrich didn't make it up. If the teeth bit is an implausible folkish element, the practice may simply serve to speed up the process—*a quick job*, perhaps *a botch job*.

It is in both cases easier to start from a common sense of cutting—indeed *to cut somebody, to skim, to card, to shave a few coins* (literally)—rather than to rely on colorful imagery.

There are so many idioms which use *über* respectively *over* to mark exaggeration that it may well be coincidence anyway. The same can be said for the sexual euphemism. I'll be fucked if that was on the books in time (NB: *~ up* must mean *open*, as of a wound, which are homophone in German *auf*).

Besides, Yiddisch has *schachern* to cover a range of senses such as vb. "barter", adj. "greedy", from Hebrew *sāḥar*. I can only wonder what its result would be in English because both thiefscant and antisemitic slurs make liberal use of lexical replacement. E.g. German *schröpfen* "to bloodlet", related to *scrape*, now also means "to make pay through the nose" as does the literal verbal phrase *jmd. zur Ader lassen*.

The phonology would be quite a stretch because argot intentionally obscures; at best it connects back to the barber, quacks and other charlatans. Besides, Low German *schäkern* "to flirt" (and more?) likely belongs to the sense of "barter" vel sim. And, *to check somebody out* could belong to a related idiom though it has plausible deniability.

If you can find *screwy* in a sense of "greed", that would be darn close. So far, there is at least a possible parallel to the sexual euphemism. I mean, I get *to nail*, but *to screw*? Come on, what are you doing!? Of course this type of *coincidence* has to be deliberate.

From the word shape it is obvious that *sk* is at any rate not inherited from Old English, because that would become *sh*.